# "hanging on the rope of"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, translation

I'm looking for two single words, a verb and a noun, with similar content, which could be best inserted in these sentences:

> In some countries workers are entirely ***_*__*_*___** <sup>**1**</sup> of/to/on their employers. No wage negotiations, no trade unions. This regularly experienced **__*_*__*_*_** <sup>**2**</sup> gravely violates human rights.
>
> <sup>**1**</sup> A verb meaning '*hanging on the rope of*', more then just 'depending on'
>   <sup>**2**</sup> Something more than 'exposedness', 'defencelessness', 'exploitation', but not as strong as 'slavery'

For those who, perhaps, know Hungarian, I'd like to find words for '*kiszolgaltatottak*' and '*kiszolgaltatottsag*' both coming from the same root 'szolga' (*servant*).

Comment: Did you look for synonyms in a thesaurus of 'dependent'?

Comment: What does “sy” (in the title) mean?  It isn't an English word.  If it's an abbreviation spell it out instead. -1.

Comment: @jwpat7 I *think* that's "somebody". However, the question can be made to work well enough without it.

Comment: @Andrew, "somebody" seems plausible.  If romist comes back and edits accordingly, I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

"Hanging on the rope of" is not an English idiom.

In the context of oppressive employers, one might say

> In some countries workers are entirely at the mercy of their employers
>   In some countries workers are entirely owned by their employers

This last description has an obvious connotation of exploitation and slavery, but it's figurative and doesn't actually indicate a real ownership and slavery.

A suitable noun would be *oppression.*

> This regularly-experienced oppression gravely violates human rights.

Comment: Maybe not by a rope, but by a thread can various hang on or by, most typically doom — or spiders. :) *And at last Ar-Pharazôn came even to Aman, the Blessed Realm, and the coasts of Valinor; and still all was silent, and doom hung by a thread. [...] There was a noise like the kicking of a flabby football, and the enraged spider fell off the branch, only catching itself with its own thread just in time. [...] Doom hangs still on a thread. [...]
How thin indeed was the thread upon which doom still hung! [...]
For he knew his deadly peril and the thread upon which his doom now hung.*

Comment: @tchrist; Your non-arachnid quotations clearly refer to the Sword of Damocles (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damocles), which both Tolkien and Dunsany would have expected their readers to recognize; it doesn't seem a helpful image here.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Leach's *at the mercy of* is excellent. If however you require that your two terms be more closely related, and both related to the idea of servitude, I suggest:

> In some countries workers are entirely ***bound*** by the will of their employers. No wage negotiations, no trade unions. This regularly experienced ***bondage*** gravely violates human rights.

Comment: *Servitude* itself seems a good noun.

Comment: @TimLymington  Yah, but I couldn't find a closely cognate adjective/participle for his first term.